# Is there a way match onRequest/onResponse calls in a RequestHook

Tags: automated-tests, hook, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a custom RequestHook and want to match calls between the onRequest and onResponse methods.  I noticed a 'requestId' in the 'event' object but would like it exposed in the API so I can use it to match the request with responses.

In my onRequest I am accessing: event._requestInfo.requestId
and in onResponse: event.requestId

Obviously, this is not ideal since they are not part of the public API.

Answer (score 2):

Using of `onRequest:event._requestInfo.requestId` and `onRequest:event.requestId` properties is the only way to combine request and response parts. This approach is also used for the build-in [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html) class (see implementation details [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/e1881ff886a2446c267c0c7f76126b2f2105b89f/src/api/request-hooks/request-logger.js#L44) and [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/e1881ff886a2446c267c0c7f76126b2f2105b89f/src/api/request-hooks/request-logger.js#L63)).

I've created a suggestion in the TestCafe repository for your use case - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3778.